# bash: Синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером ">"

Tags: bash, altlinux

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /var/log/plpu
exec > >(tee "/var/log/plpu/boot_script.log) 2>&1
echo "test"
```

При попытке запуска выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое `exec > >`?

Comment: `bash` и `sh` это разные шеллы. И в `sh` видимо нет `>(...)`

Comment: @andreymal имеете ввиду, что exec делает конкретно здесь?

Comment: @Ronin в первую очередь имею в виду, что вообще вы пытались сделать этим кодом

Comment: @andreymal перенаправить весь последующий вывод скрипта в лог и на экран

Comment: А и правда, если запускать не через sh, а как положено через bash, то это перенаправление действительно работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь, что ввел в заблуждение.

В *ALT linux* оболочка пользователя по умолчанию - `bash`, я же пытался запустить это через `sh`. Как верно указали в комментариях, это совсем разные вещи.